# SendVerificationCode are blocked by firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Firebase phone number authentication worked fine with otp. But now I'm getting Firebase exception and not getting the otp.

This is the exception-

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Requests to this API identitytoolkit method google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.AuthenticationService.SendVerificationCode are blocked. ]
```

and

```
Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/sendVerificationCode?alt=proto&key=AIz--------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

403 is for `Forbidden access`.

- Refer to the API's quota in the Firebase Console to ensure your
  application is not exceeding the request quota.
- Ensure  API is enabled in the Developer Console for the application
  you are testing.
- Confirm that the SHA key has been inserted properly .

For SMS sign in with Firebase .

> **Verification code SMS messages**:  50 messages/IP address/minute,
>   500 messages/IP address/hour
>
> **Verification requests** :  150 requests/IP address/hour

Answer (score 1):

You may have reached the limit. Please check [limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits)

Comment: you means OTP messages limits.

Comment: but new I getting error-  ' BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/sendVerificationCode?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyB7-UHeED7dtxZUo9rLlAp3DvJ8SM6WtRQ'

Comment: Have you added a test phone number to whitelisted phone numbers list for manual testing? It will not eat up your quota limits.

Comment: no i not add mobile number for test purpose because after add it i don't no how it will work

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more about the above issue you are getting?

Comment: Okay!! great :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add dummy phone number with otp for testing purpose. Firebase only allow 
**Verification code SMS messages    50 messages/IP address/minute, 500 messages/IP address/hour**. Alternatively try another phone number.